# How do I open a file on server using the default program in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qdesktopservices

Everything I read indicates that [`QDesktopServices::openUrl`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) is the platform-agnostic way to open a document using the default program, and it works great, almost all of the time.

I say almost, because it always seems to fail if I pass it a network path. Combing through the source I see that [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns error code 2.

Example:

```
QUrl localpath = QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/temp/myfile.txt");
QUrl networkpath = QUrl::fromLocalFile("//192.168.0.5/my folder/myfile.txt");

QDesktopServices::openUrl(localpath);     //works fine
QDesktopServices::openUrl(networkpath);   //always fails
```

Is there a way I can clean up a network path to open correctly? I'm running Qt 4.8 on Windows. Switching the forward slashes to backslashes doesn't help.

Comment: First and foremost you should use `QUrl::fromLocalFile` to build `file://` URLs, and not mere string concatenation. Second, I think you need to map that network path to a unit drive in order to make your shell happy. (Or is Windows just go to transparently handle such paths? I strongly doubt so, but who knows...)

Comment: Think having five slashes in a row might have something to do with it.

Comment: @peppe: I've updated the example to include `QUrl::fromLocalFile` instead of QString, but it doesn't help. I'd be shocked if the shell doesn't like network paths since _everything_ else does, but I guess I shouldn't be.

Comment: I wonder if having a space in the name (e.g. "my folder") is a problem?  You might try a path that doesn't contain a space, just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: No change. I think the Windows shell is simply incapable of handling network paths. For example, MS-DOS requires that you map a network drive first. [QProcess::startDetached](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#startDetached-2) looks like my best option.

Answer (score 1):

You should use QUrl::TolerantMode if you have spaces in your path.
try this:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:////192.168.0.5/my folder/myfile.txt", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Comment: `QUrl::TolerantMode` is already the [default mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#QUrl-2).